# belongs_to with polymorphic relationship will not delete from a has_many relationship via nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations, cocoon-gem

I am attempting to create a quite complex nested form that relies on a polymorphic relationship. I have most of it working, however this one relationship will not perform a delete like I am expecting.

`Recipe` has many `RecipeSteps`,
`RecipeSteps` can be polymorphic related to one of three things: `Techniques`, `Steps`, or `Recipes`

For some reason rails refuses to delete the `RecipeStep` when I attempt to do so from `recipes#edit` via a nested form and passing `_delete: 1` to the `RecipeStep`. The response is listed at the bottom of the code block below.

I have tried changing the `belongs_to` associated with the `RecipeStep` to `requires: false`, I have tried adding `dependent: destroy` on anything that would cause a FK error. And I have tried updating the `recipes_controller.rb` Strong Params to allow all of this info through. I am including `:_delete`, `:id`, and all other params `RecipeStep` requires.

I am not getting any errors, It just does not even attempt to do the delete.

I am using these gems:

- Cocoon
- Simple Form

---

Here is the relevant code:

## Polymorphic Relationship Concern

### stepable.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Adds the polymorphic relation to recipes through recipe_steps
module Stepable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :recipe_steps, as: :stepable
    has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_steps
  end
end
```

## Recipe

### recipe.rb - Model

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: recipes
#
#  id          :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  title       :string
#  description :text
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#

# Recipe's are containers that can have as many Steps, Techniques, or even
#   other Recipes within them.
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  include Stepable

  has_many :recipe_steps

  has_many :steps,
           through: :recipe_steps,
           source: 'stepable',
           source_type: 'Step',
           dependent: :destroy

  has_many :techniques,
           through: :recipe_steps,
           source: 'stepable',
           source_type: 'Technique',
           dependent: :destroy

  has_many :recipes,
           through: :recipe_steps,
           source: 'stepable',
           source_type: 'Recipe',
           dependent: :destroy

  has_many :ingredients,
           through: :steps

  has_many :step_ingredients,
           through: :steps,
           dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipes,
                                reject_if: :all_blank,
                                allow_destroy: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :techniques,
                                reject_if: :all_blank,
                                allow_destroy: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps,
                                reject_if: :all_blank,
                                allow_destroy: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_steps,
                                reject_if: :all_blank,
                                allow_destroy: true
end
```

### recipes_controller.rb - Controller

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_recipe, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /recipes
  # GET /recipes.json
  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all.decorate
  end

  # GET /recipes/1
  # GET /recipes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /recipes/new
  def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
  end

  # GET /recipes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /recipes
  # POST /recipes.json
  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.save
        format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /recipes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /recipes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /recipes/1
  # DELETE /recipes/1.json
  def destroy
    @recipe.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to recipes_url, notice: 'Recipe was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_recipe
      @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe)
            .permit(
              :name,
              :title,
              :description,
              recipe_steps_attributes: [
                :id,
                :position,
                :stepable_type,
                :stepable_id,
                :recipe_id,
                :_destroy
              ],
              recipes_attributes: [
                :id,
                :_destroy
              ],
              techniques_attributes: [
                :id,
                :title,
                :description,
                :_destroy
              ],
              steps_attributes: [
                :id,
                :title,
                :description,
                :_destroy,
                step_ingredients_attributes: [
                  :id,
                  :_destroy,
                  :ingredient_id,
                  measurements_attributes: [
                    :id,
                    :unit,
                    :scalar,
                    :purpose,
                    :_destroy
                  ],
                  ingredient_attributes: [
                    :id,
                    :title,
                    :description,
                    :_destroy
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            )
    end
end
```

### recipe_step.rb - Model

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: recipe_steps
#
#  id            :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  recipe_id     :bigint(8)
#  stepable_type :string
#  stepable_id   :bigint(8)
#  position      :integer
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#

# RecipeStep is the through table for relating polymorphic stepable items to
#   the recipe.
class RecipeStep < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :stepable, polymorphic: true, required: false
  belongs_to :recipe, required: false

  before_create :set_position

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stepable,
                                reject_if: :all_blank,
                                allow_destroy: true

  default_scope -> { order(position: :asc) }

  private

  def set_position
    self.position = recipe.recipe_steps.count + 1
  end
end
```

### Response

```
Started PATCH "/recipes/3" for ::1 at 2019-02-19 15:55:20 -0500
Processing by RecipesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"21JWhw/o6ysiInTGv4gJp8pTrvh5jpscpGw2Fhm2o3OyitieRz26nBGeFaZclH21zXHBhjtF7L9ujE3yILl+IQ==", "recipe"=>{"title"=>"Pizza", "description"=>"Three eggs with cilantro, tomatoes, onions, avocados and melted Emmental cheese. With a side of roasted potatoes, and your choice of toast or croissant.", "recipe_steps_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"position"=>"2", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"11"}, "1"=>{"position"=>"10", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"10"}}, "steps_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"Ricotta Stuffed Ravioli", "description"=>"Two butter croissants of your choice (plain, almond or cheese). With a side of herb butter or house-made hazelnut spread.", "step_ingredients_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"ingredient_id"=>"1", "measurements_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"unit"=>"", "scalar"=>"0.7", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"15"}, "1"=>{"unit"=>"", "scalar"=>"6.7", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"16"}, "2"=>{"unit"=>"", "scalar"=>"5.8", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"17"}}, "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"11"}}, "id"=>"10"}}}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"3"}
  Recipe Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:69
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:46
  RecipeStep Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "recipe_steps".* FROM "recipe_steps" WHERE "recipe_steps"."recipe_id" = $1 AND "recipe_steps"."id" IN ($2, $3) ORDER BY "recipe_steps"."position" ASC  [["recipe_id", 3], ["id", 11], ["id", 10]]
  ↳ app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:46
  Step Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "steps".* FROM "steps" INNER JOIN "recipe_steps" ON "steps"."id" = "recipe_steps"."stepable_id" WHERE "recipe_steps"."recipe_id" = $1 AND "recipe_steps"."stepable_type" = $2 AND "steps"."id" = $3 ORDER BY "recipe_steps"."position" ASC  [["recipe_id", 3], ["stepable_type", "Step"], ["id", 10]]
  ↳ app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:46
  StepIngredient Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "step_ingredients".* FROM "step_ingredients" WHERE "step_ingredients"."step_id" = $1 AND "step_ingredients"."id" = $2  [["step_id", 10], ["id", 11]]
  ↳ app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:46
  Measurement Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "measurements".* FROM "measurements" WHERE "measurements"."step_ingredient_id" = $1 AND "measurements"."id" IN ($2, $3, $4)  [["step_ingredient_id", 11], ["id", 15], ["id", 16], ["id", 17]]
  ↳ app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:46
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:46
Redirected to http://localhost:3100/recipes/3
Completed 302 Found in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)

Started GET "/recipes/3" for ::1 at 2019-02-19 15:55:21 -0500
Processing by RecipesController#show as HTML
```

Important Info: `"recipe_steps_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"position"=>"2", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"11"}`

As you can see, the `_destroy` argument is properly set and no un-permitted parameter errors are sent. However there is still not even an attempt to delete the `recipe_step`

I have not included the views for this error because I believe that they are functioning correctly, as can be seen by the params being passed to the controller. If you think there may be an error with my `simple form` and or `cocoon` implementation please ask and I will add those pieces of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Recipe` is related to `RecipeStep` in two ways:

1. `has_many :recipe_steps`
2. `has_many :recipe_steps, as: :stepable` via the stepable.rb concern

Having both of these be `:recipe_steps` was the issue. I changed the concern to: 
`has_many :through_steps, as: :stepable, class_name: 'RecipeStep'` and this solved the deletion issue.